# Каким образом возможно исключить диагональные оси при перемещении персонажа?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, разработка-игр, xna

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется класс `Player`, в нем прописаны соответствующие методы для вывода спрайта игрока и для обработки его логики.

Логика обрабатывается в методе `Update(...)`, в нём происходит обновление позиции, проверка на коллизии и самое главное (для этого вопроса) - обработка ввода с клавиатуры.

Вот листинг метода, который занимается обработкой ввода:

```
protected override void KeyUpdate()
{
     // Прослушивание событий с клавиатуры
     KeyboardState key = Keyboard.GetState();
     // Временный контейнер для выполнения расчетов
     Vector2 tempDirection = Direction; 

     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
     {
          tempDirection.Y = -Speed;    
     }

     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
     {       
          tempDirection.Y = Speed;
     }

     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
     {
           tempDirection.X = -Speed;
     }

     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
     {
          tempDirection.X = Speed;
     }

       Direction = tempDirection;
}
```

Вкратце поясню, каким образом работает текущая логика передвижения персонажа.

В классе `Player` определены следующие поля, необходимые для наших расчётов: `Position(X,Y)`, `Direction(X,Y)`, `Speed`.

Текущая позиция вычисляется в методе `PositionUpdate(...)`, который является частью метода `Update(...)` (все еще того же класса `Player`):

```
public void PositionUpdate(...)
{
     Position.X += Direction.X;            
     Position.Y += Direction.Y;

     Direction = new Vector2(0, 0);
}
```

Этот метод вызывается после метода `KeyUpdate(...)`.

Как вы уже могли понять, передвижение персонажа может осуществляется только при наличии ненулевого значения свойства `Direction.X/Direction.Y` по соответствующим осям.

Сами же значения `Direction` задаются как раз таки в методе `KeyUpdate(...)`, позволяя двигаться персонажу в разные стороны.

Значения извлекается из поля `Speed`, которое имеет строго фиксированное значение.

В методе `PositionUpdate(...)` осуществляется обнуление `Direction`, чтобы персонаж не продолжал двигаться бесконечно после того, как игрок отпустил клавишу.

Вроде бы за логику я все пояснил, во всяком случае надеюсь на это.

**Что я пытаюсь сделать на данный момент?**

*Исключить возможность диагонального перемещения персонажа.*

На данный момент передвижение осуществляется с учетом смещения позиции по обеим осям.

Хорошо. Пробуем исправить это:

```
protected override void KeyUpdate()
{
     // Прослушивание событий с клавиатуры
     KeyboardState key = Keyboard.GetState();
     // Временный контейнер для выполнения расчетов
     Vector2 tempDirection = Direction; 

     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
     {
          tempDirection.Y = -Speed;    
     } else
     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
     {       
          tempDirection.Y = Speed;
     } else
     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
     {
           tempDirection.X = -Speed;
     } else
     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
     {
          tempDirection.X = Speed;
     }

       Direction = tempDirection;
}
```

Отлично. Персонаж более не двигается по диагонали. Но... это не совсем то.

Если двигаться **влево** или **вправо**, то при нажатии кнопки **вверх** или **вниз** персонаж в тот же момент поворачивается в соответствующую сторону.

Получается, что я поворачиваю в другую сторону и мне нет надобности сначала отпускать кнопку движения, а потом нажимать нужную. И это удобно. *Это то, чего я пытаюсь добиться.*

Однако же если двигаться **вверх** или **вниз** и при этом попытаться повернуть **влево** или  **вправо**, то ничего не произойдет и персонаж продолжит движение вверх или вниз.

Пытаемся сделать немного по другому:

```
protected override void KeyUpdate()
{
     // Прослушивание событий с клавиатуры
     KeyboardState key = Keyboard.GetState();
     // Временный контейнер для выполнения расчетов
     Vector2 tempDirection = Direction; 

     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
     {
          tempDirection.Y = -Speed;    
     }

     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
     {       
          tempDirection.Y = Speed;
     }

     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
     {
           tempDirection.X = -Speed;
     }

     if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
     {
          tempDirection.X = Speed;
     }

     // Если имеется какое-либо передвижение по оси X
     if (tempDirection.X != 0)
     {
          // И при этом осуществляется какое-либо передвижение по оси Y
          if (tempDirection.Y != 0)
          {
               tempDirection.X = 0; // блокируем возможность движения по оси X
          } else
          {
                tempDirection.X = tempDirection.X > 0 ? Speed : -Speed;  // если нет изменений по оси Y, то двигаемся в ту или иную сторону
          } 
      }

     // Если имеется какое-либо передвижение по оси Y
     if (tempDirection.Y != 0)
     {
          // И при этом осуществляется какое-либо передвижение по оси  X
          if (tempDirection.X != 0)
          {
               tempDirection.Y= 0; // блокируем возможность движения по оси Y
          } else
          {
                tempDirection.Y= tempDirection.Y > 0 ? Speed : -Speed;  // если нет изменений по оси X, то двигаемся в ту или иную сторону
          } 
      }
       Direction = tempDirection;
}
```

И... нет. Этот способ не рабочий. Точнее, рабочий, но только наполовину. Механика поведения является преобладающей для логики кода, которая находится выше.

Т.е. в приведенном выше листинге осуществляется движение **влево**-**вправо** и имеется возможность поворота **вверх**-**вниз**, однако же при передвижении **вверх**-**вниз**, персонаж уже не может поворачиваться **влево**-**вправо**.

Но стоит поменять блоки кода местами - и ситуация становится совершенно обратной.

В конце подведу итог того, что я пытаюсь получить.

1. Блокировать возможность диагональных перемещений
2. Позволить персонажу мгновенно поворачиваться в любую доступную сторону без необходимости отпускать клавиши и нажимать нужные.

Пример: игрок жмет клавишу W и двигается вперед, но вдруг **он нажимает клавишу D и при этом не отпускает клавишу W**, **но поворот в сторону D все равно осуществляется**. И так для всех WASD клавиш соответственно.

Comment: Вам надо анализировать не только tempDirection, но и Direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно клавиатура предоставляет подписку на события *нажатия* и *отпускания* клавиши, и они вам бы помогли, потому что вы могли бы просто обрабатывать результат последней нажатой клавиши, не обращая внимания на то, какие клавиши ещё нажаты.

Я в XNA не знаток, но поиск выдал ссылку вот на эту [статью](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203902.aspx) (англ.). Для реализации нужной задачи рекомендуют хранить старое состояние клавиатуры и сравнивать его с новым. Там приведён пример кода, обратите внимание на метод `UpdateInput`.

Метод неидеальный, поскольку есть вероятность, что игрок нажмёт две кнопки очень быстро и тогда снова встанет та же дилемма — отдать предпочтение вертикали или горизонтали. Но доступа к клавиатуре на более низком уровне в XNA по видимому не предоставляется.